# usar redirect para página especifica após a validação em caso de erro - Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5.8, ancora, validation

Bom tenho o código abaixo

Validação:

```
class FormNew extends FormRequest{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {

       return [
            'email.required'        => 'campo Email Obrigatório',
            'email.email'           => 'campo Email com formato inválido',
        ];
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
class FormularioController extends Controller{

    public function newsletter(FormNew $request)
    {

        $usuarioEmail = Usuario::Where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if($usuarioEmail == null){
            $usuario = new Usuario;
            $usuario->perfil_id         = '2';
            $usuario->email             = $request->email ;
            $usuario->password          = Hash::make(rand(1,100).'senha');
            $usuario->save();
            return redirect('?#newsletters')->with('SucessoCadastro', 'Email Cadastrado com sucesso!');
        }else{
            return redirect('?#newsletters')->with('Falha', 'Email já cadastrado no sistema');
        }


    }
}
```

Observem quem no meu redirect estou usando uma ancora, pra quando o usuário submeter o form ele ir direto onde se encontra o formulário, queria saber como usar esse redirect dentro  da minha validação, pra quando der o erro ele ir p formulário para mostrar os erros (FormNew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `FormRequest` possui propriedades especiais para redirecionamento, se ela não encontrar nenhum valor ela utiliza o redirecionamento default `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::previous()`.

Você pode fazer o redirect utilizando qualquer uma das propriedades abaixo:

```
protected $redirect; // URL. ex: google.com
protected $redirectRoute; // Nome da rota.
protected $redirectAction; // Action do controller
```

```
class FormNew extends FormRequest{

    /**
     * Redirect route when errors occur.
     *  
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirect = '/teste#newsletters';

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {

       return [
            'email.required'        => 'campo Email Obrigatório',
            'email.email'           => 'campo Email com formato inválido',
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado!